# Side-chain Oxidation vs Oxidative Cleavage

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, synthesis, organic-oxidation

[image]

When the above compound is subjected to acidified $\ce{KMnO4}$, can both side chain oxidation and oxidative cleavage of $\ce{C=C}$ bond occur? Or will one have priority over the other?

Comment: It will depend on the reaction conditions used. I think it would be possible to find conditions that give majority oxidative cleavage.

Comment: @Waylander what kind of conditions would favor oxidative cleavage over side-chain oxidation? I thought the reactants and conditions are largely similar for the two?

Comment: Lower concentrations and reaction temperature. But if you want selective oxidative cleavage there are better reagents to use.